# Call method on UI thread from background in .net 2.0

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface, .net-2.0, monodevelop

I am using MonoDevelop (.net 2.0) to develop a iOS and Android app. I use BeginGetResponse and EndGetResponse to asynchronously do a webrequest in a background thread.

```
IAsyncResult result = request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(onLogin), state);
```

However, the callback `onLogin` does seem to still be running on a background thread, no allowing me to interact with the UI. How do I solve this?

Can see that there are Android and iOS specific solutions but want a cross-platform solution.

**Edit:** From mhutch answer I've got this far:

```
IAsyncResult result = request.BeginGetResponse(o => {
            state.context.Post(() => { onLogin(o); });
        }, state);
```

Where state contains a `context` variable of type `SynchronizationContext` set to `SynchronizationContext.Current`

It complains that Post requires two arguments, the second one being `Object state`. Inserting `state` gives the error

```
Argument `#1' cannot convert `anonymous method' expression to type `System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback' (CS1503) (Core.Droid)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android set a `SynchronizationContext` for the GUI thread.

This means you get the `SynchronizationContext.Current` from the GUI thread and pass it to your callback (e.g via the state object or captured in a lambda). Then you can use the context's `Post` method to invoke things on the main thread.

For example:

```
//don't inline this into the callback, we need to get it from the GUI thread
var ctx = SynchronizationContext.Current;

IAsyncResult result = request.BeginGetResponse(o => {
    // calculate stuff on the background thread
    var loginInfo = GetLoginInfo (o);
    // send it to the GUI thread
    ctx.Post (_ => { ShowInGui (loginInfo); }, null);
}, state);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Looks like this is what I was looking for. Can you give me an example where the context is passed with the `state`variable instead. Now it complains that GetLoginInfo cannot be found. And with `ShowInGui`I assume you mean `onLogin`

Comment: Right, GetLoginInfo and ShowInGui are simply examples representing code you want to run on the background threads and code you want to run in the GUI thread.

Comment: Passing context through the state object is easy. You can pass any state object to BeginGetResponse and your callback can get it from the AsyncState property of the IAsyncResult. So you can pass data to your callback that way. It's an old pattern from before anonymous delegates and lambdas were introduced.

Comment: It sais that System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Post has the arguments System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback and object. I added state as second argument to Post but then it can't convert 'anonymous method' expression to type 'System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback'.

Comment: Okay, my example was slightly wrong, Post also takes some kind of state object and passes it to the callback. Fixed it, passing null as the state objects and using _ to declare a lambda with an ignored parameter. Though in your specific case you could probably change the paramter of  `onLogin` to be of type `object`, do: `state.context.Post(onLogin, o);`, and `Post` will pass `o` to `onLogin`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this works on Mono, but I usually do this on WinForm applications. Let's suppose you want to execute the method `X()`. Then:

```
public void ResponseFinished() {
    InvokeSafe(() => X()); //Instead of just X();
}

public void InvokeSafe(MethodInvoker m) {
    if (InvokeRequired) {
        BeginInvoke(m);
    } else {
        m.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Of course, this is inside a Form class.

Comment: Form class? What should I import? "using System.Threading" does not help. It can find any of MethodInvoker, InvokeRequired, BeginInvoke or Invoke.