# Inside a platform, Android or iOS, which Rx Scheduler should be used to ObserveOn the Main Thread?

Tags: c#, xamarin, system.reactive

When using Rx.NET in a platform specific project

- Android
- iOS

How do you `ObserveOn` the main thread? It doesn't look like `ObserveOnDispatcher()` is available under iOS or Android when using Xamarin.

This sample does work, as I know I am on the main thread when I subscribe. I just didn't know if there was a more formal way to deal with: "ALWAYS" use the main thread even if I am not on the main thread.

```
myObservable // assume this does work on an alternate thread
.ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current)
.Subscribe(OnMyObservableNext);
```

Again, if I am on the main thread, say in a click event handler, I know that using `SynchronizationContext.Current` will put me back onto that thread. In testing this I have verified that as well.

What I am looking for though is the case where I may not be on the main thread and I want to get back there (from a PCL).

I can think of a solution where I store the `SynchronizationContext.Current` on a static class, in the case of iOS, in the `FinishedLaunching` method of the App Delegate. I don't know if this is advisable or not.

The solution mentioned above would be something like this:

**PCL**

```
namespace MyPCL
{

    public static class Settings
    {
        // obvioulsy probably don't want public setter, 
        // don't want anyone reaching in here and changiing it
        // from under us. But for the example this is fine.
        public static SynchronizationContext MainContext { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**iOS**

```
using MyPCL;

namespace MyApp.iOS
{
    [Register ("AppDelegate")]
    public class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
    {
        public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
        {
            // ...
            Settings.MainContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
            // ^^^^ Save the Main SynchronizationContext 
            // ...
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there isn't an out of the box scheduler that you can use.

What you have 
paired with some injection
http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/16_TestingRx.html#SchedulerDI

Is what I've seen in most recommendations
[Call method on UI thread from background in .net 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14997974/call-method-on-ui-thread-from-background-in-net-2-0)

That or if you're using Xamarin Forms just use this from the Subscribe

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/device/#Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread

Which isn't the prettiest thing to do but it works

ReactiveUI does have some custom scheduler implementations that are used for getting to the Dispatcher thread

https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/b418df64918da0c78a378af1b846afbab0f4e5ae/src/ReactiveUI/Android/AndroidUIScheduler.cs

https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/b418df64918da0c78a378af1b846afbab0f4e5ae/src/ReactiveUI/Cocoa/NSRunloopScheduler.cs

So you can try those out as well but I'm not too sure the difference/advantages of using those over the SynchronizationContext

Comment: `RxApp` requires the use of the `ReactiveUI` package, which is pegged to v 2.x.x of Reactive Extensions. Obviously there is a legitimate argument there on the pros/cons of just using `ReactiveUI`, but in the case of of not using `ReactiveUI` `RxApp.MainThreadScheduler` will not exist.

Comment: Reading fail :-( some reason I thought you were using RxUI.... Let me update my answer

Comment: Alright sorry about that @AdamVenturella  I edited my answer to hopefully be more helpful

Comment: the first link is broken. Other links don't provide a concrete answer. So what is the recommended way?